# Passing an integer value through view controllers with an addition and subtraction counter

Tags: swift, uikit, viewcontroller

I am working on a Magic the Gathering Counter app. For my app, I want to click `twentyLife()`, `thirtyLife()`, or `fourtyLife()` to change the value of a variable in another view controller (i.e. FifthViewController.)

Second view controller code:

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var vcFive = FifthViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func twentyLife() {
    vcFive.lifePoints.text = String(20)
    
}
@IBAction func thirtyLife() {
    vcFive.lifePoints.text = String(20)
    
}

@IBAction func fortyLife() {
    vcFive.lifePoints.text = String(20)
}
```

I try and call out the fifthViewController as a variable to change my life points text but it does not work.

Here is my code for the fifthViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FifthViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lifePoints: UILabel!
    var counter = 0
    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func lifeUp() {

    counter += 1
    lifePoints.text = String(counter)
}

@IBAction func lifeDown() {
    counter -= 1
    lifePoints.text = String(counter)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is my first app I have been trying to work on from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of your `FifthViewController` on your `SecondViewController`, and a variable on your `FifthViewController` in which you can save the data passed. Like this:

## SecondViewController

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let fifthVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fifthVC") as? FifthViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func twentyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 20

    }

    @IBAction func thirtyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 30

    }

    @IBAction func fortyLife() {
        fifthVC.lifePointsInt = 50
    }
}
```

## FifthViewController

```
import UIKit

class FifthViewController: UIViewController {
    var lifePointsInt = Int()
    @IBOutlet weak var lifePoints: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lifePoints.text = "\(lifePointsInt)"
    }

    @IBAction func lifeUp() {
        lifePoints.text = "\(lifePointsInt + 1)"
    }

    @IBAction func lifeDown() {
        lifePoints.text = "\(lifePointsInt - 1)"
    }
}
```

Remember to type in your Storyboard ID in your storyboard for your `FifthViewController` as `"fifthVC"` If your pass to your `FifthViewController` after selecting your Life Count in your `SecondViewController` you could add `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(fifthVC!, animated: true)` at the end of each function.

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting this error on my second view controller. Code:              Value of type '(SecondViewController) -> () -> SecondViewController' has no member 'storyboard'

Comment: Is that on a specific line of code? Is your SecondViewController on your storyboard connected with your Swift file?